# How can I find out the screen resolution and dpi on my mac book pro?

Tags: macbook, resolution, display, dpi

Can you please tell me how can I find out the screen resolution and dpi for the screen on my Macbook Pro? (I got it last year, 2009.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This depends on the model of Macbook Pro (i.e. the screen size - 13.3", 15.4" or 17") you purchased, but the resolution and DPI (or PPI), for the 2009 unibody models, is provided by Wikipedia ([here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_displays_by_pixel_density#Apple_Inc.) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook_Pro#Models_2)).

However, given the resolution and display size, you can [easily calculate](http://members.ping.de/~sven/dpi.html) the PPI. In summary:

```
MacBook Pro 13.3":  1440x900 (127.68 PPI)
MacBook Pro 15.4":  1440x900 (110.27 PPI)
MacBook Pro 15.4":  1680x1050 (128 PPI)
MacBook Pro 17":    1920x1200 (133.19 PPI)
```

Comment: Thanks. Is resolution and display size are the only factor depends on how good? So a MacBook Pro 15" 1440x900 should look the same as 15" 1440x800 laptop? But why for some reason MacBook Pro always look better, picture seems finer/sharper?

Comment: So dum that they don't print that to the display settings. Now, we have to find out what model we have...

Answer (score 57):

Open the **Apple** menu at the very top-left of the screen and click on **About This Mac**. Click on the **More Info** button, which will open up a window with lots of categories of information. The **Graphics/Displays** category will tell you your screen resolution.

Comment: Note: On Yosemite (10.10.x) there's no need to press **More Info**, as the **Displays** tab is directly accessible from **About This Mac**

Answer (score 24):

If you like terminal, then you can get via below command

```
system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType |grep Resolution
```

For example

```
>system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType |grep Resolution
          Resolution: 1920 x 1080 @ 60 Hz
```

Comment: good one, thanks for the cli option - here's the output on my ~2011 macbook air: `Resolution: 1440 x 900 (Widescreen eXtended Graphics Array Plus)`

Answer (score 2):

Or to view and change the resolution: Open the **Apple** menu at the very top-left of the screen and click on **System Preferences...**, then **Displays**. This will show a list of available resolutions with the current one highlighted.

Comment: This doesn't work well on Yosemite (OS X 10.10). The Displays preference panel doesn't show the resolutions - it just has a radio button "Best for display" or "Scaled". If you check "Scaled" it will show the resolution for an external display, but not for the retina laptop display. @jwaddell's answer *does* work though.

Comment: To calculate the DPI you do not need the (simulated) resolution but the number of (actual) pixels, I think. The latter is a fixed value (defined by the hardware); the former, though, depends on the mentioned MacBook's Display setting.

Answer (score 2):

Open Terminal app and run this command: `system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType`. You will see output that looks like this:

```
$ system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType

Graphics/Displays:

    Intel Iris Graphics 6100:

      Chipset Model: Intel Iris Graphics 6100
      Type: GPU
      Bus: Built-In
      VRAM (Dynamic, Max): 1536 MB
      Vendor: Intel (0x8086)
      Device ID: 0x162b
      Revision ID: 0x0009
      Displays:
        Color LCD:
          Display Type: Retina LCD
          Resolution: 2560 x 1600 Retina
          Retina: Yes
          Pixel Depth: 32-Bit Color (ARGB8888)
          Main Display: Yes
          Mirror: Off
          Online: Yes
          Built-In: Yes
```

Comment: Any solution without the command line?

Answer (score 1):

All these answers are good but the fastest way to find the mac resolution is to do SHIFT + COMMAND + 4 (screenshot shortcut). Move the cursor to the bottom right to get the coordinates.

Press SHIFT + COMMAND + 4 with the cursor in the bottom right corner

Source: Computer Science student at Chapel Hill

Comment: The text is black and tiny and I cannot read it when the cursor is in the corner.

Comment: To calculate the DPI you do not need the (simulated) resolution but the number of (actual) pixels, I think. The latter is a fixed value (defined by the hardware); the former, though, depends on the MacBook's Display's Font Size setting.